# How to group a list of buttons in one button?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, accordion, jsplitpane

I am working on a swing application, and i want to add a functionality and i don't know how to do it.
A part of my main frame contains a panel, which contains buttons to access other frames, and i want to add some enhancements to it, this is the picture of the panel:

[image]

And the functionality that i want to add is, when i click on the **Appel d'offre** button, i want it to list a list of the other buttons, in other words i want to group all the buttons in one.
i looked for an example to make it clear, here is a photo of Sage software:

[image]

So how am i suppose to do it, what is the components that i have to add to make it work?
i hope that i clarified my question.

Comment: You can use `setVisible` method for other buttons when the `Appel d'offre button` is clicked..

Comment: I don't want it to be like that, i want when i click on it, a list of buttons scrolls down and show the other buttons, if its possible.

Comment: If you can see on the second picture, when i click on "Gestion des ventes" it lists the contained buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These controls called *ExpandBar* or *Collapsible panel*.

Swing does not provide this type of control, but you can create your own.

Also the [swingx library](http://swingx.java.net/) provide one for example.
Guess google could help you to find more with these terms.